# Input field validation using regex in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, validation

I have a created a basic validation form in ReactJS using normal condition to validate the input fields.

Now instead of using the basic condition as I have used below I want to use regular expression to validate the input field.

My present code is this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

function Create() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [companyNumber, setCompanyNumber] = useState('');;

    const postData = () => {

        const url = `https://62c45bb0abea8c085a73b996.mockapi.io/Reactcrud`

            if(password.length <= 4){
                return Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Error',
                    text: 'password must contain atleast 4 digits',
                    showConfirmButton: true
                  })
            }else if(companyNumber.length !== 10){
                return Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Error',
                    text: 'mobile number should be a 10 digit number',
                    showConfirmButton: true
                  })
            }else{
                axios.post(url, {
                    password,
                    email,
                    companyNumber,
                })
    
            .then(() => {
                navigate('/company/list');
            })
            }
            
    }

    const goBack = () =>{
        navigate("/company/list")
    } 

    return (
        <div className='container-fluid'>
        <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-lg-4'></div>
        <div className='text-black align-content-center col-lg-5 '>
            <Form className="create-form">
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input  placeholder='enter password' onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input  placeholder='Email' onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Company Mobile Number</label>
                    <input  placeholder='Company Number' onChange={(e) => setCompanyNumber(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Button color="blue" onClick={postData} type='submit'>Submit</Button>
                 <Button color="red" onClick={goBack}>
                    Cancel
                 </Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Create;
```

In the above code for mobile number validation and password validation I have added a condition for the input to be a 10 digit number.

Now I want it to validate using this regular expression for mobile number validation:

```
const regex1 = /^(\+91[-\s]?)?[0]?(91)?[789]\d{9}$/;
```

and this for the password validation:

```
const regex2 = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{4,12}$/;
```

So as you can see I have used a basic condition to validate the input field, now I want to add a regular expression to validate both the password field and the mobile number field according to the regular expressions.

Please Help me out in achieving the validation work according to the requirement I want using the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the condition in the else if statement as below and it does the trick.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

function Create() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [companyNumber, setCompanyNumber] = useState('');;

    const postData = () => {

        const url = `https://62c45bb0abea8c085a73b996.mockapi.io/Reactcrud`

        const regex = /^(\+91[-\s]?)?[0]?(91)?[789]\d{9}$/;

            if(password.length <= 4){
                return Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Error',
                    text: 'password must contain atleast 4 digits',
                    showConfirmButton: true
                  })
            }else if(!regex.test(companyNumber)){
                return Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Error',
                    text: 'mobile number should be a 10 digit number',
                    showConfirmButton: true
                  })
            }else{
                axios.post(url, {
                    password,
                    email,
                    companyNumber,
                })
    
            .then(() => {
                navigate('/company/list');
            })
            }
            
    }

    const goBack = () =>{
        navigate("/company/list")
    } 

    return (
        <div className='container-fluid'>
        <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-lg-4'></div>
        <div className='text-black align-content-center col-lg-5 '>
            <Form className="create-form">
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input  placeholder='enter password' onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input  placeholder='Email' onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Company Mobile Number</label>
                    <input  placeholder='Company Number' onChange={(e) => setCompanyNumber(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Button color="blue" onClick={postData} type='submit'>Submit</Button>
                 <Button color="red" onClick={goBack}>
                    Cancel
                 </Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Create;
```